# Error when trying to install wine

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, wine

i'm using UBUNTU 14.04 , and i want to install wine1.6 since it the latest stable version , i tried from the command line

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

---

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 wine1.6 : Dépend: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
           Recommande: winbind mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

the error is in french , with a translator to english i get :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies :
wine : Depends : wine1.6 but will not be installed or wine1.7 but will                                     
not be installed E: Unable to correct problems , defective packets are    
mode " keep state
```

when trying to install it from the software center i get this :

```
apt://wine1.7

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine1.7: Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.50-0ubuntu1) but 1:1.7.50-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.50-0ubuntu1) but it is a virtual package
```

---

```
apt://wine1.6
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
             Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is a virtual package
```

**Update :**
i have tried to install wine 1.6.2 from the source too

```
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

after that it seems that wine haven't been installed because when typing wine i get :

```
wine : command not found
```

Any hints ?

Comment: Is there any alternatives to wine ?

Comment: Up upUp upUp upUp up

Comment: Try this [solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/697648/how-to-fix-installation-wine-on-ubuntu-14-04-3lts-64-bit/700497?noredirect=1#comment1027279_700497)

Comment: @BeGood i have run : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
`  but with `debfoster -d wine` i got
`N'est pas un paquet installé : « wine »` that means wine it's not installed ... what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me (maybe it will work for you) is to run an update of ubuntu to another release , i have installed 15.10 and i was able to install wine witout any problems because i got fresh ppa.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install wine winetricks
```

and when it comes whit the screen push enter, and it might work fine this way.

Comment: i get  ==> Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:wine-ubuntu/ubuntu'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

Comment: @Frankenstein That means you spelled it wrong. Look at the differences between your PPA and the one in the command >_>

Comment: have you tried whit wine1.7 maybe works for you.

Comment: @DavidCole  i was abble to add it now , but i still get those errors `
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 wine : Dépend: wine1.6 mais ne sera pas installé ou
                 wine1.7 mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».`

Comment: @Michael i have tried all versions and tried to install wine from the source too but without any results , plzz do you know any alternatives to wine

Comment: Frankenstien if u had bothered to translate that you would've gotten this: The following information should help you resolve the situation : The following packages have unmet dependencies : wine : Depends : wine1.6 but will not be installed or wine1.7 but will not be installed E: Unable to correct problems , defective packets are mode " keep state

Comment: @DavidCole i keep looking for a solution on different forum but without any result , i'm stuck ... maybe i will use virtualBox

Comment: @Frankenstein That might work, but you will need a working copy of windows to make a Windows virtual machine

Comment: @DavidCole yes i have already windows 7 on virtual box but it working nice but i still want to try wine :p

Comment: Alther the source.list file whit sudo -i gedit /etc/apt/source.list and then delete all wine repository and try again.

Comment: @Michael after running you command i get an empty file !!! that mean that it had just been created by using gedit

Comment: ... after all re-executing the commands did not work !!!

Comment: had to add ppa repository and add architecture as shown in response bellow

Answer (score 1):

Run this command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

before you run

```
apt-get update
```

Then you will be able to install wine.

Comment: It still doesn't work `Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 wine1.6 : Dépend: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
`

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to install a package with apt-get, because there is a conflict with an already installed package.

The solution to this problem is to install the package with aptitude rather than with apt-get . Just install aptitude with the command `apt-get install aptitude`, then just use aptitude to install the package you wanna install like this `aptitude install your-package`, aptitude will propose to install the right version of the package that are making problems.

Answer (score -1):

Some times i like to clean this up:

- Using synaptic you can go into (Installed manually) and check the wine packages to unmark them as installed manually, so apt can resolve easier things.
- doing **apt-get clean && apt-get update -qq** (qq is to silence the update)
- Trying to purge the concerned wine packages and reinstall them. **apt-get remove --purge wine1.6 wine1.6-i386 wine1.6-amd64**
- doing **apt-get install -f** will try to configure the remaining packages that previously failed to install, this may give you hints about which package to purge and try to reinstall, also the causes that made installation fail.

This may solve your problem.

Comment: sorry none of them worked , i still get the same problems