# How to fix installation wine on ubuntu 14.04.3LTS 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, wine

I knew there are a lot of questions about `wine` but i can't find or fix with there answers.
Can someone help me to fix installation about Wine please.

Here are the command output while trying to fix it:

1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

   `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Calculating upgrade... Done
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   ```
2. [`sudo apt-get update`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13365849/)
3. `sudo apt-get install wine`

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
   or been moved out of Incoming.
   The following information may help to resolve the situation:

   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                    wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```
4. `sudo apt-get install wine1.6`

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
   or been moved out of Incoming.
   The following information may help to resolve the situation:

   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```
5. `sudo apt-get install wine1.6:i386`

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
   or been moved out of Incoming.
   The following information may help to resolve the situation:

   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    wine1.6:i386 : Depends: wine1.6-i386:i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
                   Recommends: winbind:i386 but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```

---

I have also tried:

- [Trouble downloading packages list due to a “Hash sum mismatch” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)
- [How to fix Duplicate sources.list entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry)

---

- #### Update 1

  Fixed all `sudo apt-get update` erros
  But still can't `sudo apt-get install wine`
- #### Update 2

  As @Sneetsher mention to me.

  The output of the last command, Same like output of step **3**
- #### Update 3

  Per @A.B. request.

  `uname -a`

  ```
  Linux bad 3.19.0-33-generic #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```

  `lsb_release -a`

  ```
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
  Release:    14.04
  Codename:   trusty
  ```

  `apt-cache policy wine wine1.6 wine1.7`

  ```
  wine:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 1:1.7.55-0ubuntu1
    Version table:
       1:1.7.55-0ubuntu1 0
          500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
       1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 0
          500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
  wine1.6:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4
    Version table:
       1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 0
          500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
  wine1.7:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 1:1.7.55-0ubuntu1
    Version table:
       1:1.7.55-0ubuntu1 0
          500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
  ```
- #### Update 4

  Per @Sneetsher request.

  ```
  apt-cache policy acl adduser apt apt-utils aspell aspell-en at-spi2-core base-passwd binfmt-support busybox-initramfs ca-certificates cabextract colord coreutils cpio cpp cpp-4.8 cups-bsd cups-client cups-common dbus dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service debconf debconf-i18n debianutils dh-python dictionaries-common dpkg e2fslibs e2fsprogs enchant file findutils fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core fonts-droid fonts-horai-umefont fonts-liberation fonts-unfonts-core fonts-wqy-microhei gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.9-base ghostscript glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnome-exe-thumbnailer gnupg gpgv gsettings-desktop-schemas gsfonts gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x hicolor-icon-theme hunspell-en-us icoutils ifupdown imagemagick imagemagick-common init-system-helpers initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initscripts insserv iproute2 isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common iso-codes klibc-utils kmod krb5-locales libaa1 libacl1 libapparmor1 libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg4.12 libarchive-extract-perl libasn1-8-heimdal libasound2 libasound2-data libasound2-plugins libaspell15 libasyncns0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libattr1 libaudit-common libaudit1 libauthen-sasl-perl libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavc1394-0 libblkid1 libbsd0 libbz2-1.0 libc6 libcaca0 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra0 libcap2 libcapi20-3 libcdparanoia0 libcgmanager0 libcloog-isl4 libcolord1 libcolorhug1 libcomerr2 libcroco3 libcups2 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libdatrie1 libdb5.3 libdbus-1-3 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdconf1 libdebconfclient0 libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libdv4 libelf1 libenchant1c2a libencode-locale-perl libexif12 libexpat1 libffi6 libfftw3-double3 libfile-basedir-perl libfile-copy-recursive-perl libfile-desktopentry-perl libfile-listing-perl libfile-mimeinfo-perl libflac8 libfont-afm-perl libfontconfig1 libfontenc1 libfreetype6 libgcc1 libgcrypt11 libgd3 libgdbm3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgeoclue0 libgif4 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-data libglu1-mesa libgmp10 libgnutls26 libgomp1 libgpg-error0 libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port10 libgpm2 libgraphite2-3 libgs9 libgs9-common libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2 libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz0b libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libhunspell-1.3-0 libhx509-5-heimdal libice6 libicu52 libidn11 libiec61883-0 libieee1284-3 libijs-0.35 libilmbase6 libio-html-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libisl10 libjack-jackd2-0 libjasper1 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libjson-c2 libjson0 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libklibc libkmod2 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 liblcms2-2 libldap-2.4-2 libldb1 libllvm3.4 liblocale-gettext-perl liblog-message-simple-perl liblqr-1-0 libltdl7 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl liblzma5 libmagic1 libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libmailtools-perl libmodule-pluggable-perl libmount1 libmpc3 libmpdec2 libmpfr4 libmpg123-0 libncurses5 libncursesw5 libnet-http-perl libnet-libidn-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnetpbm10 libnih-dbus1 libnih1 libnotify4 libntdb1 libodbc1 libogg0 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenexr6 liborc-0.4-0 libosmesa6 libp11-kit0 libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam-systemd libpam0g libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpcap0.8 libpciaccess0 libpcre3 libpipeline1 libpixman-1-0 libplymouth2 libpng12-0 libpod-latex-perl libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpopt0 libprocps3 libproxy1 libpulse0 libpython-stdlib libpython2.7 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3-stdlib libpython3.4-minimal libpython3.4-stdlib libraw1394-11 libreadline6 libroken18-heimdal librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsamplerate0 libsane libsane-common libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common libselinux1 libsemanage-common libsemanage1 libsepol1 libshout3 libslang2 libsm6 libsmbclient libsndfile1 libsocket6-perl libsoup2.4-1 libspeex1 libspeexdsp1 libsqlite3-0 libss2 libssl1.0.0 libstdc++6 libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-login0 libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a libtalloc2 libtasn1-6 libtdb1 libterm-ui-perl libtevent0 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-soundex-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libthai-data libthai0 libtheora0 libtiff5 libtimedate-perl libtinfo5 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libudev1 liburi-perl libusb-0.1-4 libusb-1.0-0 libustr-1.0-1 libuuid1 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libvpx1 libwavpack1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwebp5 libwind0-heimdal libwmf0.2-7 libwrap0 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-xcb1 libxau6 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxfont1 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxml2 libxmu6 libxmuu1 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxslt1.1 libxt6 libxtables10 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 lsb-base lsb-release makedev mime-support module-init-tools mount mountall multiarch-support netbase netpbm notification-daemon ocl-icd-libopencl1 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 openssl p11-kit-modules p7zip passwd patch perl perl-base perl-modules plymouth plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text policykit-1 poppler-data procps psmisc python python-apt python-apt-common python-chardet python-crypto python-debian python-ldb python-minimal python-ntdb python-samba python-six python-talloc python-tdb python2.7 python2.7-minimal python3 python3-apt python3-minimal python3.4 python3.4-minimal readline-common samba-common samba-common-bin samba-libs sed sensible-utils sgml-base shared-mime-info smbclient sound-theme-freedesktop sudo systemd-services systemd-shim sysv-rc sysvinit-utils tar tcpd ttf-mscorefonts-installer ttf-wqy-microhei tzdata ubuntu-keyring ucf udev unixodbc unzip update-inetd update-notifier-common upstart util-linux uuid-runtime wget wine-gecko2.34 wine-mono4.5.4 wine1.7 wine1.7-amd64 wine1.7-i386 winetricks x11-common x11-utils x11-xserver-utils xdg-utils xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils xkb-data xml-core xz-utils zenity zenity-common zip zlib1g
  ```

  Full output was uploaded [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13336818/).
- #### Update 5

  After I could install wine as suggested by Sneetsher. I still can't run `.exe` files using wine. Screenshot belowis for:

  `wine ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/notepad.exe` is top window. And both windows in the bottom are for `OLLYDBG.EXE` by clicking on it.

  I can't make any edit through notepad.

  [image]

  ```
  $ wine --version
  wine-1.6.2
  $ which wine
  /usr/local/bin/wine
  ```

---

Please, let me know If I have to provide more information.

Comment: please try `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and `sudo apt-get install wine`

Comment: I have install wine on 64bit and 32bit and i have never did this `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` have you tried to regenerate your `sources.list` file ?

Comment: You should fix the `Duplicate sources.list entry` and `Hash Sum mismatch` issues first, since they will make a solution of the `wine` installation issue much more tedious.

Comment: @DavidFoerster can you guide me to fix Hash Sum?

Comment: @BeGood: Please search for existing (should be easy with these error messages) or open new questions for these issues. Ping me, if you want my input on them.

Comment: @Neil Can u provide more information about regenerate sources.list

Comment: @BeGood all you do is delete `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list` **You will need to add you're PPA's back if you do this**. Then you open software-properties `sudo software-properties-gtk` and tick `Canonical` , `Community`,`Propietary`,`Software restricted ` then click Close then Reload.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for helping me but still apear same error

Comment: @BeGood , Could you give aptitude a try as step 6-8 ONLY in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/677668/26246 , but look for `wine` (NOT for `wine:i368`) before applying please post what aptitude trying to remove.

Comment: @Sneetsher Can u give a look about this [Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/698062/how-to-ignore-remove-package-from-aptitude)
That was not full note about `aptitude` because of more than 45k words

Comment: @Sneetsher `grep -ir arch /etc/dpkg/ ` didn't show output . and `echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch` Permission denied

Comment: @BeGood, no need for that step you have Ubuntu 14.04 that was for Ubuntu 12.04. Ok I will check the other question.

Comment: This really needs to be resolved by the wine package maintainers. I suggest filing a bug report asking to resolve the dependencies.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen you mean report to bug launchpad?

Comment: Yes, on launchpad. It is sort of a long standing problem.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Take a look please [Link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wine/+bug/1229221/comments/14)

Comment: As I said, it is a bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.6/+bug/1313123 "this was originally a series of concurrent issues, some of which have been fixed. There are now separate bugs for the remaining issues (backport of wine1.6 to trusty" so you are affected by the outstanding bugs in the backport repository. disable the backports repo and try again.

Comment: Oh i did disable repo and try again. @Ravan recommended

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `uname -a; lsb_release -a; apt-cache policy wine wine1.6 wine1.7` After that run `apt-cache showpkg wine wine1.6 wine1.7` and add this output here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/. and give me a link and a ping in the comments with `@A.B.`

Comment: @A.B. http://paste.ubuntu.com/13344492/ here sir

Comment: Please add the output of all following commands here http://paste.ubuntu.com/ I need the output of `apt-cache showpkg wine wine1.7; sudo apt-get install wine1.7`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13347119/ @A.B.

Comment: The output of `apt-cache policy wine1.7-i386`

Comment: Can you please show the output of <code>dpkg -l *wine*</code>

Comment: @sibaz http://paste.ubuntu.com/13353972/

Comment: @A.B. http://paste.ubuntu.com/13353977/

Comment: This question already solved through chat in his other related question, [link here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31646/discussion-between-begood-and-sneetsher). Quiet messy chat history. I will report here later.

Comment: Sorry, you need to run <code>dpkg -l *wine* </code> from a folder not containing any files matching that name, or it won't work.  Try <code>dpkg -l "*wine*" </code> as that paste bin was a bit pointless

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will be kind of resume to the trials in the comments above and [the related chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31646/discussion-between-begood-and-sneetsher) where it was resolved.

What we tried without success:

- Enable i386 architecture `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, as Wine needs many dependencies from the 32bit repositories.
- OP created new [`sources.list`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13335808/) with all components enabled.
- Disabled all PPA's (Check with `grep -r "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`)
- `aptitude` which gives many solutions but all were trying to remove most of the installed desktop packages (>200 packages) or keep it as it is without installing Wine.
- Installing 1.6 instead 1.7 `sudo apt-get install wine=1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4`, same unresolved dependencies message.
- Tracking the conflict down using `apt-get install`, then got branches.

  ```
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libglu1-mesa:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 or
  libgl1:i386
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```

  It is not practical to search for conflict this way, waste of efforts and time consuming.

So what we are looking for could be a far (not direct) dependency package:

- Not available in official repositories + Wine PPA.
- Or installed but has a version not from official repositories + Wine PPA.

  (ie. installed version is higher than those available from repositories. `apt-get` & `aptitude` do not provide solutions with downgrading some packages)

Here are resumed steps:

1. Add back Wine PPA
2. I installed `debfoster` on my machine with same release of OP's system (14.04). Generate list of all recursive dependencies of wine:

   ```
   debfoster -d wine
   ```

   (Why is this? OP can't run this on his machine because `debfoster` like `apt-cache` works only for installed packages)
3. Asked the OP to provide the output of `apt-cache policy ...` for the list generated in the previous step. (Update 4, in the question)
4. Then stored previous output and filtered it for easy review:

   ```
   grep -e "^[a-zA-Z]" -e "^[ ]*\*\*\*" -e "^[ ]*[1-9]00" -e "^[* ]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z:+_~.-]* 0" wine_policy_output.txt
   ```
5. Found these packages:

   ```
   libdrm-intel1:
    *** 2.4.65+git20151026.c745e541-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty 0
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
        2.4.60-2~ubuntu14.04.1 0
           500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        2.4.56-1~ubuntu2 0
           500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        2.4.52-1 0
           500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
   libdrm-nouveau2:
    *** 2.4.65+git20151026.c745e541-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty 0
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
        2.4.60-2~ubuntu14.04.1 0
           500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        2.4.56-1~ubuntu2 0
           500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        2.4.52-1 0
           500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
   libdrm-radeon1:
    *** 2.4.65+git20151026.c745e541-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty 0
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
        2.4.60-2~ubuntu14.04.1 0
           500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        2.4.56-1~ubuntu2 0
           500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        2.4.52-1 0
           500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
   libdrm2:
    *** 2.4.65+git20151026.c745e541-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty 0
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
        2.4.60-2~ubuntu14.04.1 0
           500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        2.4.56-1~ubuntu2 0
           500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        2.4.52-1 0
           500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

   libwayland-client0:
    *** 1.7.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1 0
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
        1.4.0-1ubuntu1 0
           500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
   libwayland-cursor0:
    *** 1.7.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1 0
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
        1.4.0-1ubuntu1 0
           500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
   ```

   These seem from [“xorg-edgers fresh X crack”](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=trusty). Downgrade them to the version available in repository:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install \
     libdrm2=2.4.60-2~ubuntu14.04.1 \
     libdrm-intel1=2.4.60-2~ubuntu14.04.1 \
     libdrm-nouveau2=2.4.60-2~ubuntu14.04.1 \
     libdrm-radeon1=2.4.60-2~ubuntu14.04.1 \
     libwayland-client0=1.4.0-1ubuntu1 \
     libwayland-cursor0=1.4.0-1ubuntu1
   ```
6. Still couldn't install wine, we looked for any other suspected package:

   ```
   libcgmanager0:
    *** 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1 0
           100 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
        0.24-0ubuntu7.5 0
           500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        0.24-0ubuntu7.1 0
           500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        0.24-0ubuntu5 0
           500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
   ```

   This one: 1st point, it is from backports. 2nd point, the current version 0.39 is too far from 0.24 in the stable repo. Downgrade it:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libcgmanager0=0.24-0ubuntu7.5
   ```
7. Now, `wine` installation passed well

   ```
   sudo aptitude install wine
   ```

About the rendering issue, the windows are grayed. As it seems from `wine --version` 1.6 but we have installed 1.7 & `which wine` brought that system have a local version of wine installed from source.

Try `echo $PATH`, you have some thing like:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

See..the variable PATH, it is where the system looks for executable. So writing just `wine` in shell, it will look in `/usr/local/sbin` folder, if not found then `/usr/local/bin` then `/usr/sbin` then `/usr/bin`...

Quick fix, removing that local copy of wine:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/wine*
```

If you want to keep it, you may run wine with full path:

```
/usr/bin/wine ...
```

**Update:**

I could reproduce same problem on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 installation. I confirm that the only troubling package is `libcgmanager0` version `0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1` which I don't know how it got installed in the first place.

The packages from [“xorg-edgers fresh X crack”](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=trusty) PPA are clean and I had suggested downgrading them as a procedure to isolate the problem.

**References:**

- [How can I get recursively list an apt package's dependencies with their installed versions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188964/12209)

Comment: Great answer and `debfoster`, too. (Tomorrow I have again votes)

Comment: OP stands for and should it mark answer that or wating your edit?

Comment: @BeGood :) OP = *Original Poster*  , ref: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms

Answer (score 0):

> "After I could install wine as suggested by Sneetsher. I still can't run >.exe files using wine."

Right click on the exe file and select properties. Then check "Allow executing as program" in the Permissions tab or open a terminal window and
{chmod +x */path/to/file/file.exe*}

Comment: It was a corrupted local copy of wine in `/usr/local/bin/`. Removing it fixed it, mentioned in the chat room and just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use aptitude instead of apt-get. It is more intelligent. It not only will handle downgrading conflicting packages for you, but will make a series of recommendations asking you which of many possible suggested working scenarios you would like.

```
sudo aptitude install myNewPackage
```

If you don't have aptitude on your machine yet, get it with

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Answer (score 0):

The next solution worked for me:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386

add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds

apt-get update

apt-get install --install-recommends wine
```

pass above commands under the root

Found it here: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

Open **Software and Updates** and under **Other Software** tab

- Enable Canonical Partner Repository.

Under **Updates tab** enable,

- Recommended updates
- Unsupported updates

Select "Close" and "Reload"

It is better to tick above unchecked repositories one by one. Then "Close", "Reload" and then execute `sudo apt-get install wine`

So you can find out exactly what repository you are missing.

Comment: Still appear same error

Answer (score -6):

Try this:

```
  sudo -i
  sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
  sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

and push enter when it comes whit linens screen, and it might work fine this way.

Comment: didn't work same error like sudo apt-get install wine1.6

Comment: Try to delete the source.list file, and use settings and update, and hatch the upper chaniocal, and then use the terminal and enter this: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa

Comment: Can you give me detail abouot delete source.list ? your mean `rm -r` . 
And what is hatch the upper chaniocal. if i did that, what issuse would i take?

Comment: @Michael `sudo bash` is, in general, less good than `sudo - i` or `sudo - s`, which set up the environment (with slight differences between the two) and are also fewer characters to type. Also in a larger network environment there are accountability benefits IIRC

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any sense in `sudo bash` or why this should solve the problem...

Comment: I would try use sudo -i and then thunar and delete the file.

Comment: Use thunar it might work fine