# Can run winetricks but can't install playonlinux on wine 1.6 Ubuntu 14.04.3LTS 64bit

Tags: 14.04, wine, playonlinux

As i mention in Q. I have wine 1.6 and my `winetricks` can run with this `wine`

```
$wine --version  
$wine-1.6.2
```

---

```
$sudo apt-get install playonlinux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 playonlinux : Depends: wine or
                        wine-unstable but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

via Ubuntu Software Center
[image]

---

```
apt-cache policy wine
wine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
     1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

---

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can i fix this problem?.

Please let me know If I have to provide more information

Comment: please [edit] question and add output of `apt-cache policy wine`

Comment: done! updated Q @Ravan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install wine with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

then install playonlinux by the command,

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Comment: @Ranvan i wish i could give [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/697648/how-to-fix-installation-wine-on-ubuntu-14-04-3lts-64-bit) to you early :D