# How to ignore remove package from aptitude

Tags: apt

As i mention in Q.

```
sudo aptitude install wine1.6
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:                                            
1)      account-plugin-aim                                                      
2)      account-plugin-facebook                                                 
3)      account-plugin-flickr                                                   
4)      account-plugin-google                                                   
5)      account-plugin-jabber                                                   
6)      account-plugin-salut                                                    
7)      account-plugin-twitter                                                  
8)      account-plugin-windows-live                                             
9)      account-plugin-yahoo                                                    
10)     appmenu-qt5                                                             
11)     apturl                                                                  
12)     brasero                                                                 
13)     checkbox-gui                                                            
14)     cheese                                                                  
15)     codeblocks                                                              
16)     compiz                                                                  
17)     compiz-gnome                                                            
18)     compiz-plugins-default                                                  
19)     deja-dup-backend-gvfs                                                   
20)     empathy                                                                 
21)     eog                                                                     
22)     friends-facebook                                                        
23)     friends-twitter                                                         
24)     gimp                                                                    
25)     gimp-gmic                                                               
26)     gimp-plugin-registry                                                    
27)     gir1.2-rb-3.0                                                           
28)     gir1.2-totem-1.0                                                        
29)     gir1.2-webkit-3.0                                                       
30)     gnome-contacts                                                          
31)     gnome-control-center                                                    
32)     gnome-font-viewer                                                       
33)     gnome-screensaver                                                       
34)     gnome-session-bin                                                       
35)     gnome-settings-daemon                                                   
36)     gnome-user-guide                                                        
37)     gstreamer1.0-clutter                                                    
38)     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad                                                
39)     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad                                           
40)     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers                                   
41)     gvfs                                                                    
42)     gvfs-backends                                                           
43)     gvfs-daemons                                                            
44)     gvfs-fuse                                                               
45)     hud                                                                     
46)     indicator-bluetooth                                                     
47)     indicator-keyboard                                                      
48)     intel-gpu-tools                                                         
49)     libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth                                         
50)     libaccount-plugin-google                                                
51)     libcheese-gtk23                                                         
52)     libcheese7                                                              
53)     libclutter-1.0-0                                                        
54)     libclutter-gst-2.0-0                                                    
55)     libclutter-gtk-1.0-0                                                    
56)     libcodeblocks0                                                          
57)     libcogl-pango15                                                         
58)     libcogl15                                                               
59)     libdrm-intel1                                                           
60)     libdrm-nouveau2                                                         
61)     libdrm-radeon1                                                          
62)     libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid                                                  
63)     libgbm1                                                                 
64)     libgbm1-lts-vivid                                                       
65)     libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid                                               
66)     libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid                                               
67)     libglew1.10                                                             
68)     libglewmx1.10                                                           
69)     libglu1-mesa                                                            
70)     libgnome-desktop-3-7                                                    
71)     libgoa-backend-1.0-1                                                    
72)     libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0                                           
73)     libgtkglext1                                                            
74)     libnux-4.0-0                                                            
75)     libopencv-calib3d2.4                                                    
76)     libopencv-contrib2.4                                                    
77)     libopencv-core2.4                                                       
78)     libopencv-features2d2.4                                                 
79)     libopencv-flann2.4                                                      
80)     libopencv-highgui2.4                                                    
81)     libopencv-imgproc2.4                                                    
82)     libopencv-legacy2.4                                                     
83)     libopencv-ml2.4                                                         
84)     libopencv-objdetect2.4                                                  
85)     libopencv-video2.4                                                      
86)     liboxideqt-qmlplugin                                                    
87)     liboxideqtcore0                                                         
88)     liboxideqtquick0                                                        
89)     libqt4-opengl                                                           
90)     libqt5feedback5                                                         
91)     libqt5gui5                                                              
92)     libqt5multimedia5                                                       
93)     libqt5opengl5                                                           
94)     libqt5printsupport5                                                     
95)     libqt5quick5                                                            
96)     libqt5svg5                                                              
97)     libqt5webkit5                                                           
98)     libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin                                           
99)     libqt5widgets5                                                          
100     libqtwebkit-dev                                                         
101     libqtwebkit4                                                            
102     libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer                                   
103     libreoffice-base-core                                                   
104     libreoffice-calc                                                        
105     libreoffice-core                                                        
106     libreoffice-draw                                                        
107     libreoffice-gnome                                                       
108     libreoffice-gtk                                                         
109     libreoffice-help-en-gb                                                  
110     libreoffice-help-en-us                                                  
111     libreoffice-help-vi                                                     
112     libreoffice-impress                                                     
113     libreoffice-math                                                        
114     libreoffice-ogltrans                                                    
115     libreoffice-pdfimport                                                   
116     libreoffice-presentation-minimizer                                      
117     libreoffice-writer                                                      
118     librhythmbox-core8                                                      
119     libtotem0                                                               
120     libunity-core-6.0-9                                                     
121     libunity-webapps0                                                       
122     libvisual-0.4-plugins                                                   
123     libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid                                          
124     libwebkitgtk-1.0-0                                                      
125     libwebkitgtk-3.0-0                                                      
126     libwxgtk2.8-0                                                           
127     libxatracker2-lts-vivid                                                 
128     libyelp0                                                                
129     mcp-account-manager-uoa                                                 
130     mencoder                                                                
131     mplayer                                                                 
132     mythes-en-us                                                            
133     nautilus                                                                
134     nautilus-sendto                                                         
135     nautilus-sendto-empathy                                                 
136     nautilus-share                                                          
137     nux-tools                                                               
138     nvidia-355                                                              
139     openjdk-7-jre                                                           
140     python-qt4                                                              
141     python3-uno                                                             
142     qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin                                          
143     qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin                                           
144     qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin                                    
145     qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin                                        
146     qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin                                          
147     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin                          
148     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin                                 
149     qtdeclarative5-window-plugin                                            
150     rhythmbox                                                               
151     rhythmbox-mozilla                                                       
152     rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder                                             
153     rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune                                              
154     rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist                                              
155     rhythmbox-plugins                                                       
156     shotwell                                                                
157     signon-plugin-oauth2                                                    
158     signon-ui                                                               
159     software-center                                                         
160     steam-launcher                                                          
161     totem                                                                   
162     totem-mozilla                                                           
163     totem-plugins                                                           
164     ubuntu-desktop                                                          
165     ubuntu-docs                                                             
166     ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk                                             
167     ubuntu-session                                                          
168     ubuntu-sso-client-qt                                                    
169     ubuntu-tweak                                                            
170     unity                                                                   
171     unity-control-center                                                    
172     unity-control-center-signon                                             
173     unity-greeter                                                           
174     unity-lens-applications                                                 
175     unity-scope-gdrive                                                      
176     unity-settings-daemon                                                   
177     unity-tweak-tool                                                        
178     unity-webapps-common                                                    
179     unity-webapps-qml                                                       
180     unity-webapps-service                                                   
181     unsettings                                                              
182     update-manager                                                          
183     update-notifier                                                         
184     virtualbox-5.0                                                          
185     vlc                                                                     
186     webaccounts-extension-common                                            
187     webapp-container                                                        
188     webbrowser-app                                                          
189     x11-utils                                                               
190     xorg                                                                    
191     xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid                                             
192     xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid                                        
193     xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-vivid                                      
194     xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-vivid                                      
195     xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid                                  
196     xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-vivid                                    
197     xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-vivid                                      
198     xserver-xorg-lts-vivid                                                  
199     xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid                                        
200     xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-vivid                                                                              


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  account-plugin-aim{a} account-plugin-facebook{a} account-plugin-flickr{a} 
  account-plugin-google{a} account-plugin-jabber{a} account-plugin-salut{a} 
  account-plugin-twitter{a} account-plugin-windows-live{a} 
  account-plugin-yahoo{a} appmenu-qt5{a} apturl{a} apturl-common{u} attr{u} 
  brasero{a} checkbox-gui{a} checkbox-ng{u} checkbox-ng-service{u} 
  cheese{a} codeblocks{a} codeblocks-common{u} compiz{a} compiz-gnome{a} 
  compiz-plugins-default{a} deja-dup-backend-gvfs{a} empathy{a} 
  empathy-common{u} eog{a} folks-common{u} friends-facebook{a} 
  friends-twitter{a} geoclue-2.0{u} gimp{a} gimp-gmic{a} 
  gimp-plugin-registry{a} gir1.2-gconf-2.0{u} gir1.2-gmenu-3.0{u} 
  gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0{u} gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0{u} 
  gir1.2-rb-3.0{a} gir1.2-secret-1{u} gir1.2-totem-1.0{a} 
  gir1.2-webkit-3.0{a} gnome-contacts{a} gnome-control-center{a} 
  gnome-font-viewer{a} gnome-screensaver{a} gnome-session-bin{a} 
  gnome-session-common{u} gnome-settings-daemon{a} gnome-user-guide{a} 
  gnome-video-effects{u} gstreamer0.10-nice{u} 
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good{u} gstreamer0.10-x{u} gstreamer1.0-clutter{a} 
  gstreamer1.0-nice{u} gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad{a} 
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad{a} gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers{a} 
  gvfs{a} gvfs-backends{a} gvfs-daemons{a} gvfs-fuse{a} hud{a} 
  indicator-bluetooth{a} indicator-keyboard{a} intel-gpu-tools{a} 
  laptop-detect{u} launchpad-getkeys{u} libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth{a} 
  libaccount-plugin-google{a} libaio1{u} libavahi-gobject0{u} 
  libcdr-0.0-0{u} libcheese-gtk23{a} libcheese7{a} libclutter-1.0-0{a} 
  libclutter-gst-2.0-0{a} libclutter-gtk-1.0-0{a} libcodeblocks0{a} 
  libcogl-pango15{a} libcogl15{a} libdmapsharing-3.0-2{u} libdrm-intel1{a} 
  libdrm-nouveau2{a} libdrm-radeon1{a} libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid{a} 
  libexiv2-12{u} libfarstream-0.1-0{u} libfarstream-0.2-2{u} 
  libfolks-eds25{u} libfolks-telepathy25{u} libfolks25{u} libfs6{u} 
  libgbm1{a} libgbm1-lts-vivid{a} libgexiv2-2{u} 
  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid{a} libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid{a} libglade2-0{u} 
  libglew1.10{a} libglewmx1.10{a} libglu1-mesa{a} libgnome-desktop-3-7{a} 
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1{a} libgpod-common{u} libgpod4{u} libgssdp-1.0-3{u} 
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0{a} libgtkglext1{a} libgupnp-1.0-4{u} 
  libgupnp-igd-1.0-4{u} libhdb9-heimdal{u} libhud2{u} libkdc2-heimdal{u} 
  liblcms1{u} libmeanwhile1{u} libmission-control-plugins0{u} 
  libmspub-0.0-0{u} libnice10{u} libnss-winbind{u} libnux-4.0-0{a} 
  libopencv-calib3d2.4{a} libopencv-contrib2.4{a} libopencv-core2.4{a} 
  libopencv-features2d2.4{a} libopencv-flann2.4{a} libopencv-highgui2.4{a} 
  libopencv-imgproc2.4{a} libopencv-legacy2.4{a} libopencv-ml2.4{a} 
  libopencv-objdetect2.4{a} libopencv-video2.4{a} liborcus-0.6-0{u} 
  liboxideqt-qmlplugin{a} liboxideqtcore0{a} liboxideqtquick0{a} 
  libpam-winbind{u} libpurple-bin{u} libpurple0{u} libqt4-opengl{a} 
  libqt5feedback5{a} libqt5gui5{a} libqt5multimedia5{a} libqt5opengl5{a} 
  libqt5organizer5{u} libqt5printsupport5{a} libqt5qml-graphicaleffects{u} 
  libqt5quick5{a} libqt5svg5{a} libqt5webkit5{a} 
  libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin{a} libqt5widgets5{a} 
  libqtassistantclient4{u} libqtwebkit-dev{a} libqtwebkit4{a} libraw9{u} 
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer{a} libreoffice-base-core{a} 
  libreoffice-calc{a} libreoffice-core{a} libreoffice-draw{a} 
  libreoffice-gnome{a} libreoffice-gtk{a} libreoffice-help-en-gb{a} 
  libreoffice-help-en-us{a} libreoffice-help-vi{a} libreoffice-impress{a} 
  libreoffice-l10n-vi{u} libreoffice-math{a} libreoffice-ogltrans{a} 
  libreoffice-pdfimport{a} libreoffice-presentation-minimizer{a} 
  libreoffice-writer{a} librhythmbox-core8{a} libsdl-ttf2.0-0{u} 
  libsgutils2-2{u} libtelepathy-farstream3{u} libtelepathy-logger3{u} 
  libthumbnailer0{u} libtiff-tools{u} libtotem0{a} libufe-xidgetter0{u} 
  libunity-action-qt1{u} libunity-core-6.0-9{a} libunity-webapps0{a} 
  libvisio-0.0-0{u} libvisual-0.4-plugins{a} 
  libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid{a} libwebkitgtk-1.0-0{a} 
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0{a} libwxbase2.8-0{u} libwxgtk2.8-0{a} 
  libxatracker2-lts-vivid{a} libyelp0{a} libzephyr4{u} 
  mcp-account-manager-uoa{a} media-player-info{u} mencoder{a} mplayer{a} 
  mythes-en-us{a} nautilus{a} nautilus-sendto{a} nautilus-sendto-empathy{a} 
  nautilus-share{a} nux-tools{a} nvidia-355{a} oneconf{u} oneconf-common{u} 
  openjdk-7-jre{a} plainbox-provider-checkbox{u} 
  plainbox-provider-resource-generic{u} plainbox-secure-policy{u} 
  ppa-purge{u} python-appindicator{u} python-debtagshw{u} python-dirspec{u} 
  python-dnspython{u} python-glade2{u} python-httplib2{u} python-keyring{u} 
  qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin{a} qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin{u} 
  rhythmbox{a} rhythmbox-data{u} rhythmbox-mozilla{a} 
  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder{a} rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune{a} 
  rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist{a} rhythmbox-plugins{a} samba{u} 
  samba-dsdb-modules{u} samba-vfs-modules{u} shotwell{a} shotwell-common{u} 
  signon-plugin-oauth2{a} signon-plugin-password{u} signon-ui{a} 
  software-center{a} software-center-aptdaemon-plugins{u} steam-launcher{a} 
  tdb-tools{u} telepathy-gabble{u} telepathy-haze{u} telepathy-logger{u} 
  telepathy-mission-control-5{u} telepathy-salut{u} totem{a} 
  totem-mozilla{a} totem-plugins{a} ubuntu-desktop{a} ubuntu-docs{a} 
  ubuntu-extras-keyring{u} ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk{a} ubuntu-session{a} 
  ubuntu-sso-client{u} ubuntu-sso-client-qt{a} ubuntu-tweak{a} 
  ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme{u} ubuntuone-client-data{u} unity{a} 
  unity-control-center{a} unity-control-center-signon{a} unity-greeter{a} 
  unity-lens-applications{a} unity-scope-gdrive{a} unity-settings-daemon{a} 
  unity-tweak-tool{a} unity-webapps-common{a} unity-webapps-qml{a} 
  unity-webapps-service{a} unsettings{a} update-manager{a} 
  update-notifier{a} virtualbox-5.0{a} vlc{a} 
  webaccounts-extension-common{a} webapp-container{a} webbrowser-app{a} 
  winbind{u} x11-apps{u} x11-session-utils{u} x11-utils{a} x11-xfs-utils{u} 
  xclip{u} xinit{u} xorg{a} xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid{a} 
  xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid{a} xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-vivid{a} 
  xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-vivid{a}  
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 360 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 1,422 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] n
Abort.
```

Please help me i need wine1.6 so much , it's 1.4GB application size:(
I cant' use `apt-get` because of [My Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697648/how-to-fix-installation-wine-on-ubuntu-14-04-3lts-64-bit)

Comment: Could you join this chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31646/discussion-between-begood-and-sneetsher

Answer (score 0):

Try using `apt-get` instead of `aptitude`. It may be a little less friendly but its dependency resolver often does a better job.

Comment: Can't if i can do it i will do but i cant'

Comment: I don't follow. You can't use apt-get? Why not?

Comment: [My question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/697648/how-to-fix-installation-wine-on-ubuntu-14-04-3lts-64-bit)

Comment: Ah, so this is a follow-up to another question. Maybe link to it in the main body as well? That way other people won't get confused as I did. In the meantime, what happens if you run `sudo apt-get install wine1.6 wine1.6:i386 wine1.6-i386` (*id est*, manually specify the iependencies)? Feel free to use `aptitude`  if you prefer.

Comment: Everything is in my link i gave you

Comment: No, actually, it isn't. I read the link, but it doesn't contain output from specifying the problematic dependency manually as I just suggested, from which I assume you haven't tried it.

Comment: Can help me @Darael ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm inclined to suspect that the underlying problem is the difficulties you're having with `apt-get update`, and I can't fix those but I *can* offer a workaround,once you've dealt with the duplicate `sources.list` entries: change mirrors. Use a regional one (you can change from the "software sources" settings box and you'll bypass any caching that might be causing problems.

Comment: is it importal? i mean it will update failed?. Anyway if this Question useful give me an upvote :D i really need 50 reputaion

Comment: I'll upvote the original question, but this one isn't really useful by itself. Re importance: if you aren't able to download the correct repository indices, which is what the hash error and the 404 are about, apt (be that apt-get or aptitude) can't resolve dependencies right, so it can't work out how to install things.

Comment: Hence the issues you're seeing.

Comment: Changing to a different mirror *should* help it get the right versions of the indices, at which point installing wine *should* work fine.

Comment: Fixed Hash miss match