# How to debug an unmet dependencies problem?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, debugging

Note about possible duplicate:

AFAIK, This is not a duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246/26246) otherwise please prove it by solving the test problem I mention below using any answer from there.

---

## Background:

I faced this problem before [How to fix installation wine on Ubuntu 14.04.3LTS 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/q/697648/26246). It was solved by manual/human review of all recursive dependencies of the target package (`wine`).

#### Reproduce the problem (Test Case):

Let's create same situation quiet simplified with just 1 trouble package.

1. Install fresh Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox.
2. Open `software-properties-gtk` and enable `backports` repository.
3. Get last packages list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Run `apt-get -s install wine` to confirm that `wine` can be installed.
5. Install the troubling package `libcgmanager0` from backports

   ```
   $ apt-cache policy libcgmanager0
   libcgmanager0:
     Installed: 0.24-0ubuntu5
     Candidate: 0.24-0ubuntu7.5
     Version table:
        0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1 0
           100 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
        0.24-0ubuntu7.5 0
           500 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        0.24-0ubuntu7.1 0
           500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
    *** 0.24-0ubuntu5 0
           500 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```

   Force `apt` to install `libcgmanager0` version `0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libcgmanager0=0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1
   ```

Now we end up in same situation of the user from the mentioned question in the background, wine installation fails with unmet dependency, showing only the first level dependency packages.

- `apt-get -s install wine`

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
  requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
  distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
  or been moved out of Incoming.
  The following information may help to resolve the situation:

  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```
- `apt-get -s install wine1.6`

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
  requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
  distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
  or been moved out of Incoming.
  The following information may help to resolve the situation:

  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```
- `apt-get -s install wine1.6-i386`

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
  requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
  distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
  or been moved out of Incoming.
  The following information may help to resolve the situation:

  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   wine1.6-i386:i386 : Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                libglu1:i386
                       Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgphoto2-port10:i386 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```

It is not practical to follow dependencies with `apt-get install` one by one.

#### Ideal Solution:

The real issue here

1. `apt` couldn't install `libcgmanager0:i386` version `0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1` because backports repository have a lower priority `100` less then version `0.24-0ubuntu7.5` from `updates` repository with `500`
2. `apt` couldn't install `libcgmanager0:i386` version `0.24-0ubuntu7.5` because `libcgmanager0:amd64` is installed with a different version `0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1`

The quickest fix is, to force installing same i386 version from backports

```
sudo apt-get install libcgmanager0:i386=0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1
```

or downgrade it (amd64) to any version from regular repositories

```
sudo apt-get install libcgmanager0=0.24-0ubuntu7.5
```

---

#### Ways/tools I have tried:

- Disabling PPA's has no relation to the problem.
- Using `aptitude`in interactive mode, brings only solutions with many removes (**>200 !!!**).
- Use `apt-get install` manually following the dependency tree. Unpractical, as the first & second level dependencies didn't raise meaningful message about the conflict.
- `debfoster` can generate the recursive dependencies but only for already installed package. However `wine` is not yet installed.

## Topic / My interests:

Let's say I want to install wine without knowing about the problem of  `libcgmanager0` package (or exactly `libcgmanager0:amd64=0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1` that already installed).

I'm looking for a debug method or a way to know the name of the troubling package and to understand quickly what was going on.

1. How to debug  unmet dependencies problems in general?

   May be there some new options in `dpkg`/`apt`/`aptitude` that trace the internal dependency resolver. That can show `libcgmanager0` in its output.
2. If there is no canonical answer to this, Could anyone show me a better way to generate the recursive dependencies list or simulate the dependency resolver with more details which can help fix the problem?

   Why all dependencies? Because I want to check the output of the below commands for all packages at once.

   - `apt-cache policy <all-dependencies>`
   - `apt-get -s install <all-dependencies>`

Comment: Just curious: Why do you need the `backports` version?

Comment: @muru, Believe me I don't know, but the OP in that question was having that package version installed. I don't even know how he got to that situation.  Let me try get same situation using a package a PPA instead.

Comment: @muru,  well I just retest all packages related that question, the PPA was clean and the only problem was this package from backports. :/ it seems, this case is rare to happen: only if a package was installed by user from low priority repo (like backports) or one dependency package fails to build (even for one arch). May be I should drop the question.

Comment: looks like it's worth filing a bug with the package maintainer

Comment: @muru, I agree for 2nd case (dependency package fails to build) to fill a bug report, but for 1st case (low priority repo) it like pinned or hold version which is a user setup problem. However, my objective from the question how to know the name of the package creating the conflict. Because for that question It took me much time to find out which package making trouble. I feel may be I wasn't clear enough, please let me know if i should explain what i need differently ?

Comment: So the problem isn't with `libcgmanager`, but with a dependency? You mentioned recursively listing dependencies. Have you tried `apt-rdepends`?

Comment: @muru, Well, let me rephrase it, If you were not knowing how I created this problem,  could tell me how you can know it is from package named  `libcgmanager0`?

Comment: @muru, `apt-rdepends` shows the dependencies perfect, but still I have to find the conflict myself.

Comment: What happens if you try to install `wine` (or other affected package) with `-o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes`?

Comment: @muru ,  thank you it solves my problem. I have seen it before in https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/26246 `sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade` I don't remember may be i missed to use it with `apt-get install ...` . Even `aptitude install ..` too does  mention the conflict clearly , but i don't know why the OP output missing that conflict package note in https://askubuntu.com/q/698062/26246. Could you please write an answer including `apt-rdepends` to be used instead of `debfoster`.

Comment: I think you'd be better placed to write the answer, since you're more familiar with the problem and what's going on.

Comment: @muru thank you very much for help. I still feel that I didn't explain my question well. I will try to rewrite/reorganize it in coming  days.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Root cause for this case (Wine has a multi-architecture package)

After few years here in Ask Ubuntu. I could notice one thing that could help for this case.

- `apt`, `aptitude` & `dpkg` don't indicate architecture if it is main the one (`amd64` generally), so they always show package-name without the architecture. While they put the architecture suffix on other architectures `package-name:i368` for example.

This creates confusion for new users as it happened to me. I was going with assumption that they are same package. examples:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
         libcgmanager0 : Breaks: libcgmanager0:i386 (!= 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1) but 0.24-0ubuntu7.5 is to be installed.
         libcgmanager0:i386 : Breaks: libcgmanager0 (!= 0.24-0ubuntu7.5) but 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1 is installed.
```

They actually mean this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
         libcgmanager0:amd64 : Breaks: libcgmanager0:i386 (!= 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1) but 0.24-0ubuntu7.5 **is to be** installed.
         libcgmanager0:i386 : Breaks: libcgmanager0:amd64 (!= 0.24-0ubuntu7.5) but 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1 **is** installed.
```

### Things to watch for resolve general unmet dependency case

- Dependencies *package name*

  Some include major version as part of *package name* NOT *package version*.
- Dependencies *package architecture*

  Default architecture is not mentioned. Common installed systems are `amd64` there may be exceptions. Most conflict happen as in this case one of the architectures  will not install or upgrade if the other architecture of same package is not available with same version. This is already declared in the package dependency condition.
- Dependencies *package source*

  Conflict usually come when dealing with external repositories and ppa's.

### Helpful Debug & Troubleshooting commands

Credits & Thanks go to [@muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru).

I was looking any command or debug option that can show me the trouble package name (`libcgmanager0` in this test case).

- [`apt-get -s -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install wine`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/13942723/)

It has a verbose output, quiet hard to understand it. It should be fine, if I get familiar with it.

- [`echo q | aptitude -s install wine`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/13942788/)

Minimum output but clear notice about the conflict.

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libcgmanager0 : Breaks: libcgmanager0:i386 (!= 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1) but 0.24-0ubuntu7.5 is to be installed.
     libcgmanager0:i386 : Breaks: libcgmanager0 (!= 0.24-0ubuntu7.5) but 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1 is installed.
```

Another point I was looking for, is to minimize the output requested from the OP support here in Ask Ubuntu. Instead for requesting `apt-cache policy` for just 1st/2nd level dependencies. I would request it for all recursive dependencies all at once.

- [`apt-rdepends wine 2>/dev/null | grep "^[a-zA-Z]" | sort`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/13943615/)

Be aware that `apt-rdepends` is emulating `apt-cache` so its result may be different than of `debfoster`. Another point, both tools do not distinguish between arch (i386 or amd64), they just show names.

```
    apt-cache policy $(apt-rdepends wine 2>/dev/null | grep "^[a-zA-Z]" | sort | paste -s -d" ")
```

As link above may be removed later, here is the full output of all commands above.

```
$ apt-get -s -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install wine
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) libudev1 [ i386 ] < none -> 204-5ubuntu20.15 > ( libs )
Broken libudev1:i386 Depends on libcgmanager0 [ i386 ] < none -> 0.24-0ubuntu7.5 | 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1 > ( admin )
  Considering libcgmanager0:i386 1 as a solution to libudev1:i386 4
  Holding Back libudev1:i386 rather than change libcgmanager0:i386
Investigating (0) libusb-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < none -> 2:1.0.17-1ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libusb-1.0-0:i386 Depends on libudev1 [ i386 ] < none -> 204-5ubuntu20.15 > ( libs ) (>= 183)
  Considering libudev1:i386 4 as a solution to libusb-1.0-0:i386 1
  Holding Back libusb-1.0-0:i386 rather than change libudev1:i386
Investigating (0) libgl1-mesa-glx [ i386 ] < none -> 11.0.4~git20151026+11.0.ec14e6f8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty > ( libs )
Broken libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 Depends on libudev1 [ i386 ] < none -> 204-5ubuntu20.15 > ( libs )
  Considering libudev1:i386 4 as a solution to libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 0
  Holding Back libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 rather than change libudev1:i386
Investigating (0) libsane [ i386 ] < none -> 1.0.23-3ubuntu3.1 > ( libs )
Broken libsane:i386 Depends on libusb-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < none -> 2:1.0.17-1ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 2:1.0.8)
  Considering libusb-1.0-0:i386 1 as a solution to libsane:i386 0
  Holding Back libsane:i386 rather than change libusb-1.0-0:i386
Investigating (0) libgphoto2-port10 [ i386 ] < none -> 2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2.2 > ( libs )
Broken libgphoto2-port10:i386 Depends on libusb-1.0-0 [ i386 ] < none -> 2:1.0.17-1ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 2:1.0.8)
  Considering libusb-1.0-0:i386 1 as a solution to libgphoto2-port10:i386 -1
  Holding Back libgphoto2-port10:i386 rather than change libusb-1.0-0:i386
Investigating (0) libgphoto2-6 [ i386 ] < none -> 2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2.2 > ( libs )
Broken libgphoto2-6:i386 Depends on libgphoto2-port10 [ i386 ] < none -> 2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2.2 > ( libs ) (>= 2.5.2)
  Considering libgphoto2-port10:i386 -1 as a solution to libgphoto2-6:i386 -1
  Holding Back libgphoto2-6:i386 rather than change libgphoto2-port10:i386
Investigating (0) libglu1-mesa [ i386 ] < none -> 9.0.0-2 > ( libs )
Broken libglu1-mesa:i386 Depends on libgl1-mesa-glx [ i386 ] < none -> 11.0.4~git20151026+11.0.ec14e6f8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty > ( libs )
  Considering libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 0 as a solution to libglu1-mesa:i386 -1
  Holding Back libglu1-mesa:i386 rather than change libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
Broken libglu1-mesa:i386 Depends on libgl1 [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 0 as a solution to libglu1-mesa:i386 -1
  Holding Back libglu1-mesa:i386 rather than change libgl1:i386
  Or group keep for libglu1-mesa:i386
Investigating (1) wine1.6-i386 [ i386 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken wine1.6-i386:i386 Depends on libglu1-mesa [ i386 ] < none -> 9.0.0-2 > ( libs )
  Considering libglu1-mesa:i386 -1 as a solution to wine1.6-i386:i386 -1
  Holding Back wine1.6-i386:i386 rather than change libglu1-mesa:i386
Broken wine1.6-i386:i386 Depends on libglu1 [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering libglu1-mesa:i386 -1 as a solution to wine1.6-i386:i386 -1
  Holding Back wine1.6-i386:i386 rather than change libglu1:i386
  Or group keep for wine1.6-i386:i386
Broken wine1.6-i386:i386 Depends on libgphoto2-6 [ i386 ] < none -> 2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2.2 > ( libs ) (>= 2.5.2)
  Considering libgphoto2-6:i386 -1 as a solution to wine1.6-i386:i386 -1
  Holding Back wine1.6-i386:i386 rather than change libgphoto2-6:i386
Investigating (2) wine1.6 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken wine1.6:amd64 Depends on wine1.6-i386 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none ) (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
  Considering wine1.6-i386:i386 -1 as a solution to wine1.6:amd64 0
  Holding Back wine1.6:amd64 rather than change wine1.6-i386:amd64
Investigating (2) wine1.6-amd64 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken wine1.6-amd64:amd64 Depends on wine1.6:any [ amd64 ] < none > ( none ) (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
  Considering wine1.6:i386 -1 as a solution to wine1.6-amd64:amd64 -1
  Holding Back wine1.6-amd64:amd64 rather than change wine1.6:any:amd64
Investigating (3) wine [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken wine:amd64 Depends on wine1.6 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
  Considering wine1.6:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9999
  Re-Instated wine1.6-amd64:amd64
    Reinst Failed because of libcgmanager0:i386
    Reinst Failed because of libudev1:i386
    Reinst Failed because of libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
    Reinst Failed because of libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
    Reinst Failed because of libglu1-mesa:i386
    Reinst Failed because of libglu1-mesa:i386
    Reinst Failed because of wine1.6-i386:i386
Investigating (3) wine1.6-amd64 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken wine1.6-amd64:amd64 Depends on wine1.6:any [ amd64 ] < none > ( none ) (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
  Considering wine1.6:i386 -1 as a solution to wine1.6-amd64:amd64 -1
  Holding Back wine1.6-amd64:amd64 rather than change wine1.6:any:amd64
Investigating (4) wine [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken wine:amd64 Depends on wine1.6 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
  Considering wine1.6:amd64 0 as a solution to wine:amd64 9999
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


$ echo q | aptitude -s install  wine
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  attr{a} binfmt-support{a} cabextract{a} fonts-horai-umefont{a} fonts-unfonts-core{a} fonts-wqy-microhei{a} gcc-4.8-base:i386{a} 
  gcc-4.9-base:i386{a} gnome-exe-thumbnailer{a} icoutils{a} imagemagick{a} imagemagick-common{a} libaio1{a} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libasound2:i386{a} libasound2-plugins:i386{a} libasyncns0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} libavahi-common-data:i386{a} 
  libavahi-common3:i386{a} libc6:i386{a} libcapi20-3{a} libcapi20-3:i386{a} libcgmanager0:i386{ab} libcomerr2:i386{a} 
  libcups2:i386{a} libdb5.3:i386{a} libdbus-1-3:i386{a} libdrm-amdgpu1{a} libdrm-amdgpu1:i386{a} libdrm-intel1:i386{a} 
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386{a} libdrm-radeon1:i386{a} libdrm2:i386{a} libedit2:i386{a} libelf1:i386{a} libencode-locale-perl{a} 
  libexif12:i386{a} libexpat1:i386{a} libffi6:i386{a} libfftw3-double3{a} libfile-listing-perl{a} libflac8:i386{a} 
  libfont-afm-perl{a} libfontconfig1:i386{a} libfreetype6:i386{a} libgcc1:i386{a} libgcrypt11:i386{a} libgd3:i386{a} libgif4{a} 
  libgif4:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-glx:i386{a} libglapi-mesa:i386{a} libglib2.0-0:i386{a} libglu1-mesa:i386{a} 
  libgnutls26:i386{a} libgpg-error0:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port10:i386{a} libgpm2:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} 
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386{a} libgstreamer0.10-0:i386{a} libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libhdb9-heimdal{a} libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} libhtml-form-perl{a} libhtml-format-perl{a} 
  libhtml-parser-perl{a} libhtml-tagset-perl{a} libhtml-tree-perl{a} libhttp-cookies-perl{a} libhttp-daemon-perl{a} 
  libhttp-date-perl{a} libhttp-message-perl{a} libhttp-negotiate-perl{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} libice6:i386{a} 
  libieee1284-3:i386{a} libilmbase6{a} libio-html-perl{a} libjack-jackd2-0:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{a} libjpeg-turbo8:i386{a} 
  libjpeg8:i386{a} libjson-c2:i386{a} libk5crypto3:i386{a} libkdc2-heimdal{a} libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libkrb5-3:i386{a} libkrb5support0:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} libllvm3.6{a} libllvm3.6:i386{a} liblqr-1-0{a} 
  libltdl7:i386{a} liblwp-mediatypes-perl{a} liblwp-protocol-https-perl{a} liblzma5:i386{a} libmagickcore5{a} libmagickcore5-extra{a} 
  libmagickwand5{a} libmpg123-0{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libncurses5:i386{a} libnet-http-perl{a} libnetpbm10{a} libnih-dbus1:i386{a} 
  libnih1:i386{a} libnss-winbind{a} libodbc1{a} libogg0:i386{a} libopenal-data{a} libopenal1{a} libopenal1:i386{a} libopenexr6{a} 
  liborc-0.4-0:i386{a} libosmesa6{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} libpam-winbind{a} 
  libpciaccess0:i386{a} libpcre3:i386{a} libpng12-0:i386{a} libpulse0:i386{a} libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} libsamplerate0:i386{a} 
  libsane:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libselinux1:i386{a} libsm6:i386{a} 
  libsndfile1:i386{a} libspeexdsp1:i386{a} libsqlite3-0:i386{a} libssl1.0.0:i386{a} libstdc++6:i386{a} libtasn1-6:i386{a} 
  libtiff5:i386{a} libtinfo5:i386{a} libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386{a} libudev1:i386{a} libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} libuuid1:i386{a} 
  libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libvorbis0a:i386{a} libvorbisenc2:i386{a} libvpx1:i386{a} libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libwrap0:i386{a} libwww-perl{a} libwww-robotrules-perl{a} libx11-6:i386{a} libx11-xcb1:i386{a} libxau6:i386{a} 
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386{a} libxcb-dri3-0:i386{a} libxcb-glx0:i386{a} libxcb-present0:i386{a} libxcb-sync1:i386{a} libxcb1:i386{a} 
  libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxcursor1:i386{a} libxdamage1:i386{a} libxdmcp6:i386{a} libxext6:i386{a} libxfixes3:i386{a} libxi6:i386{a} 
  libxinerama1:i386{a} libxml2:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a} libxrender1:i386{a} libxshmfence1:i386{a} 
  libxslt1.1:i386{a} libxt6:i386{a} libxxf86vm1:i386{a} netpbm{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} odbcinst{a} 
  odbcinst1debian2{a} p11-kit-modules:i386{a} p7zip{a} python-dnspython{a} samba{a} samba-dsdb-modules{a} samba-vfs-modules{a} 
  tdb-tools{a} ttf-mscorefonts-installer{a} ttf-wqy-microhei{a} unixodbc{a} winbind{a} wine wine-gecko2.21{a} wine-gecko2.21:i386{a} 
  wine-mono0.0.8{a} wine1.6{a} wine1.6-amd64{a} wine1.6-i386:i386{a} winetricks{a} zlib1g:i386{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgl1-mesa-dri 
1 packages upgraded, 210 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 200 MB of archives. After unpacking 646 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcgmanager0 : Breaks: libcgmanager0:i386 (!= 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1) but 0.24-0ubuntu7.5 is to be installed.
 libcgmanager0:i386 : Breaks: libcgmanager0 (!= 0.24-0ubuntu7.5) but 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)      libcgmanager0:i386 [Not Installed]                 
2)      libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 [Not Installed]               
3)      libglu1-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]                  
4)      libgphoto2-6:i386 [Not Installed]                  
5)      libgphoto2-port10:i386 [Not Installed]             
6)      libsane:i386 [Not Installed]                       
7)      libudev1:i386 [Not Installed]                      
8)      libusb-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                  
9)      wine [Not Installed]                               
10)     wine1.6 [Not Installed]                            
11)     wine1.6-amd64 [Not Installed]                      
12)     wine1.6-i386:i386 [Not Installed]                  

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
13)     winetricks recommends wine                         


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Abandoning all efforts to resolve these dependencies.
Abort.


$ apt-rdepends wine 2>/dev/null | grep "^[a-zA-Z]" | sort
adduser
base-passwd
binfmt-support
busybox-initramfs
coreutils
cpio
debconf
debconf-2.0
debianutils
dpkg
file-rc
findutils
fontconfig-config
fonts-dejavu-core
fonts-freefont-ttf
gcc-4.8-base
gcc-4.9-base
gsfonts
gsfonts-x11
ifupdown
initramfs-tools
initramfs-tools-bin
initscripts
init-system-helpers
insserv
install-info
iproute2
iso-codes
klibc-utils
kmod
libacl1
libasn1-8-heimdal
libasound2
libasound2-data
libasyncns0
libattr1
libaudit1
libaudit-common
libblkid1
libbz2-1.0
libc6
libcgmanager0
libcomerr2
libdb5.3
libdbus-1-3
libdebconfclient0
libdrm2
libexif12
libexpat1
libffi6
libflac8
libfontconfig1
libfontenc1
libfreetype6
libgcc1
libgcrypt11
libgd3
libgdbm3
libgl1
libgl1-mesa-glx
libglapi-mesa
libglib2.0-0
libglu1
libglu1-mesa
libgnutls26
libgpg-error0
libgphoto2-6
libgphoto2-port10
libgssapi3-heimdal
libgstreamer0.10-0
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
libhcrypto4-heimdal
libheimbase1-heimdal
libheimntlm0-heimdal
libhx509-5-heimdal
libjbig0
libjpeg8
libjpeg-turbo8
libjson0
libjson-c2
libklibc
libkmod2
libkrb5-26-heimdal
liblcms2-2
libldap-2.4-2
libltdl7
liblzma5
libmount1
libmpg123-0
libncurses5
libncursesw5
libnih1
libnih-dbus1
libogg0
libopenal1
libopenal-data
libopencl1
libopencl-1.1-1
liborc-0.4-0
libp11-kit0
libpam0g
libpam-modules
libpam-modules-bin
libpcre3
libpipeline1
libplymouth2
libpng12-0
libprocps3
libpulse0
libroken18-heimdal
libsasl2-2
libsasl2-modules-db
libselinux1
libsemanage1
libsemanage-common
libsepol1
libslang2
libsndfile1
libsqlite3-0
libstdc++6
libtasn1-6
libtiff5
libtinfo5
libudev0
libudev1
libusb-1.0-0
libustr-1.0-1
libuuid1
libvorbis0a
libvorbisenc2
libvpx1
libwind0-heimdal
libwrap0
libx11-6
libx11-data
libx11-xcb1
libxau6
libxcb1
libxcb-dri2-0
libxcb-dri3-0
libxcb-glx0
libxcb-present0
libxcb-sync1
libxdamage1
libxdmcp6
libxext6
libxfixes3
libxfont1
libxml2
libxpm4
libxshmfence1
libxxf86vm1
lsb-base
makedev
module-init-tools
mount
mountall
multiarch-support
ocl-icd-libopencl1
passwd
perl
perl-base
perl-modules
plymouth
procps
sensible-utils
sysvinit-utils
sysv-rc
tar
ttf-bitstream-vera
tzdata
ucf
udev
upstart
util-linux
wine
wine1.6
wine1.6-amd64
wine1.6:any
wine1.6-i386
x11-common
xfonts-encodings
xfonts-utils
zlib1g
```