# Package dependency problems with broken packages but none listed to fix

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

I am trying to install wine on Ubuntu 15.04, I had it working before but I think something went wrong with 32 or 64 bit installations so I tried removing it to start again.

Now I am trying to install it again but running `apt-get install wine`

```
root@pc-ubuntu:/home/dav# apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`
```

So I try to fix the broken packages with `apt-get install -f`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.`
```

I have tried removing and adding the PPA, I have tried a load of other commands pointed out in the answer here [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)
But none of them have worked either. I'm stuck, please any suggestions would be amazing to fix this as I would like to sort it before attempting to build the latest wine 1.8 from source.
Thanks

Comment: Can you remove any package without `dpkg --force`?

Comment: Yes, no problem...
`root@pc-ubuntu:/home/dav# apt-get remove ppa-purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  ppa-purge
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 45.1 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to format the comments nicely

Comment: Try `apt-get dist upgrade` and send the results

Comment: that outputs

`root@pc-ubuntu:/home/dav# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.`

So no problems there either...

Comment: None of your packages are broken. The wine dependencies are conflicting with each other. Uninstall existing version of wine (if exists) then install wine1.7 (there won't be such problem with wine1.7)

Comment: If you didn't fix this yet, post the output of the commands from this answer  http://askubuntu.com/a/708647/26246

Answer (score 1):

None of your packages are broken. The wine dependencies are conflicting with each other. Uninstall existing version of wine (if exists) then install wine1.7 (there won't be such problem with wine1.7)

**UPDATE:**
To install wine 1.7 on your case type these in your terminal:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install wine1.7`

Comment: There is no version installed, `apt-get remove wine` shows nothing to do. So do I simply run `apt-get install wine1.7`?

Comment: Yes, I said uninstall if exists.

Comment: Coming up with the same problems.
`root@pc-ubuntu:/home/dav# apt-get install wine1.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine1.7 is a virtual package provided by:
  winehq-staging 1.9.0~ubuntu14.04.1
  winehq-devel 1.9.0~ubuntu14.04.1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'wine1.7' has no installation candidate`. When I try to install winehq-staging or winehq-devel I get the original errors about holding broken packages

Comment: **You should explicitly select one to install.**
`root@pc-ubuntu:/home/dav# apt-get install winehq-staging
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: I will update the answer.

Comment: Still the same problems, see the output here: https://jsbin.com/fatokawubo/edit?output. Any other help would be appreciated thanks