# Error with vlc installation, dependency

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, vlc

I recently updated Ubuntu 14.04 from software updater. After update some packages were removed. after that I found that vlc has been also removed from my system. So I tried to install vlc and its giving a error like this:

```
mzsbulbul@bulbul-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1-3~ubuntu14.04.1~c42.ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.1-3~ubuntu14.04.1~c42.ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.1-3~ubuntu14.04.1~c42.ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have also tried `sudo apt-get -f install & sudo aptitude install vlc` but not solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug an unmet dependencies problem?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/707333/how-to-debug-an-unmet-dependencies-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Add the repository universe:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
```

update package:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install `vlc` :

```
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

More explained by https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Installing_VLC/#Ubuntu

```
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc
```