# Eclipse - Package dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, eclipse

I know there are a lot of questions on this topic, and I tried a lot of options that worked for some people, but I just cannot get this done. I am trying to install Eclipse on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and whenever I do this I get this message. I tried with `autoclean`, `autoremove`, `upgrade` and other stuff, also with `sudo apt-get install -f` but nothing works. Any other solution?

This is what i get as an error:

> Package dependencies cannot be resolved
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> eclipse-platform: Depends: ant (>= 1.8.2) but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: ant-optional but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: eclipse-platform-data (>= 3.8.1-5.1) but 3.8.1-5.1 is to be installed
>
> Depends: eclipse-rcp (= 3.8.1-5.1) but 3.8.1-5.1 is to be installed
>
> Depends: libcommons-codec-java (>= 1.4-2) but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: libcommons-httpclient-java (>= 3.1-9) but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: libcommons-logging-java (>= 1.1.1-6) but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: libjsch-java (>= 0.1.37-3) but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: liblucene2-java (< 2.9.5) but 2.9.4+ds1-4 is to be installed
>
> Depends: libservlet3.0-java but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: sat4j (< 2.4.0) but 2.3.2-1 is to be installed

Comment: The `eclipse` package from the repository is very outdated. Get the latest version from the official Eclipse website and follow their installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

After having similar problems with wine I found this answer which helped me locate the errors and solve them.

[How to debug an unmet dependencies problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707333/how-to-debug-an-unmet-dependencies-problem)