# Wine dependency problem on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, dependencies

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** on **Dell Vostro 3546**

```
uname -a

Linux <host-name> 4.15.0-122-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 13:03:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linu
```

I am having severe wine dependency problems. This started when I did `sudo apt-get purge wine*`. I am not able to install it back. Please help, wine is very essential for me.

1. 32-bit architecture is enabled
2. Output of `sudo apt-get update`, just for you to look at my repositories list : https://pastebin.com/416d1fRU
3. Output of normal `winehq-stable` installation: https://pastebin.com/JvK1MrCb
4. Output of `winehq-stable` installation using my favourite dependency tool: https://pastebin.com/tKBpRbe5.
   If I choose "Y" in the first prompt it will do nothing and just exit. Then, in the second prompt if I choose "Y" it completely ruins my system by removing everything. If I choose "n", then it will ask again and again to do the same thing. Had to "q" abort.
5. Using synaptic:

   [image: synaptic]

**EDIT:**

```
apt-cache policy winehq-stable wine-stable


winehq-stable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.2~bionic
  Version table:
     5.0.2~bionic 500
        500 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Packages
wine-stable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.2~bionic
  Version table:
     5.0.2~bionic 500
        500 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Packages
     3.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.2~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Output of `apt-cache policy $(apt-rdepends winehq-stable 2>/dev/null | grep "^[a-zA-Z]" | sort | paste -s -d" ")` = https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7phckZ5nsD/

Output of `apt-cache policy $(apt-rdepends wine-stable 2>/dev/null | grep "^[a-zA-Z]" | sort | paste -s -d" ")` = https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Cp89PtzZks/

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy winehq-stable wine-stable`? Also, 3 and 4 have the same paste's link.

Comment: @Kulfy I added the output, sorry for the 3 and 4 same output, I edited it.

Comment: @karel none of them worked

Comment: @GopalS Would you install `apt-rdepends` then upload output of `apt-cache policy $(apt-rdepends wine 2>/dev/null | grep "^[a-zA-Z]" | sort | paste -s -d" ")` to https://paste.ubuntu.com and include link in the question.

Comment: @user.dz Oh yeah, check now in the question itself

Comment: @GopalS not as as before, output empty. could you try again: `apt-cache policy $(apt-rdepends winehq-stable 2>/dev/null | grep "^[a-zA-Z]" | sort | paste -s -d" ")` and `apt-cache policy $(apt-rdepends wine-stable 2>/dev/null | grep "^[a-zA-Z]" | sort | paste -s -d" ")` By the way I'm following this https://askubuntu.com/q/707333/26246 if you are the explorer type

Comment: @user.dz I did as you said.

Comment: @GopalS You seems to have a multiarch (amd64, i386) dependency issue, you need to enable i386 for that wine v5 or downgrade to Ubuntu wine v3 . Would you share your repository sources setup : `more /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: @user.dz Do look into this chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115786/room-for-technastic-tc-and-gopal-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully solved this issue with [technastic_tc](https://askubuntu.com/users/1103140/technastic-tc) and [user.dz](https://askubuntu.com/users/26246/user-dz).

I had accidentally disabled `bionic-updates`, I then re-enabled `bionic-updates` repository from `software-properties-gtk`.
Voila ! I again tried `sudo aptitude install winehq-stable`. It worked !!!

Thanks a lot.