# Broken packages - wine

Tags: package-management, software-installation, wine, dependencies

i can't install wine on my linux(xUbuntu 14.04 x64)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
           Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what to do?

Comment: Refer [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/697648/how-to-fix-installation-wine-on-ubuntu-14-04-3lts-64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

First remove the remaining dispensaries by

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove wine
```

The fix the broken packages via

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The reinstall wine if you want

Comment: "sudo apt-get purge wine" no nees for remove and purge https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto (For 32bit ubuntu download wine from software center is recommended)

Comment: it had no effect at all - when i tried to reinstall wine, it again said : The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
           Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.