# Unable to install Wine after uninstall

Tags: apt, 16.04, wine

I have installed Wine a year ago when I had Ubuntu 14.04. Now I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and lately I have had problems with SSD which led to the deletion of my Wine Windows environment. I tried creating a new environment but it didn't work so I had to uninstall wine. I purged it, and tried to install it again but I am getting:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

More info:

```
$ sudo apt-cache show wine1.6
Package: wine1.6
Priority: optional
Section: universe/otherosfs
Installed-Size: 2996
Maintainer: Scott Ritchie <scottritchie@ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14
Replaces: wine, wine1.0, wine1.2, wine1.3, wine1.4, wine1.5
Provides: wine
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, libc6 (>= 2.17), wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14), binfmt-support (>= 1.1.2), procps, wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14)
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~)
Recommends: cups-bsd, gnome-exe-thumbnailer | kde-runtime, fonts-droid, fonts-liberation, ttf-mscorefonts-installer, fonts-horai-umefont, fonts-unfonts-core, ttf-wqy-microhei, winetricks, xdg-utils
Suggests: dosbox:any, winbind
Conflicts: wine1.0, wine1.2, wine1.3
Filename: pool/universe/w/wine1.6/wine1.6_1.6.2-0ubuntu14_amd64.deb
Size: 864090
MD5sum: 7b1047b8678cd0a5e1ba382d2e26b6cf
SHA1: 305d77542b21be17621aa657d2e8c8e275897d34
SHA256: 9a81f55e883662ed92c36143255947d5382b2c5b3b5c20b5721b4074cd34f077
Description-en: Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (Binary Emulator and Library)
 Wine is a compatibility layer for running Windows applications on Linux.
 Applications are run at full speed without the need of cpu emulation. Wine
 does not require Microsoft Windows, however it can use native system dll
 files in place of its own if they are available.
 .
 This package includes a program loader for running unmodified Windows
 executables as well as the Wine project's free version of the Windows API for
 running programs ported from Windows.
Description-md5: 06ea04f761f0f961a93a88bc585f4ba8
Multi-Arch: allowed
Homepage: http://www.winehq.org/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Using aptitude:

```
$ sudo aptitude install wine1.6
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-horai-umefont{a} fonts-unfonts-core{a} fonts-wqy-microhei{a} 
  gnome-exe-thumbnailer{a} icoutils{a} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libcapi20-3{a} libcapi20-3:i386{a} libexif12:i386{a} libgd3:i386{ab} 
  libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port12:i386{a} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libieee1284-3:i386{a} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} 
  libltdl7:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libodbc1{a} libopenal1:i386{a} 
  libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386{a} 
  libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} libsane:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} 
  libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} 
  libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libvpx3:i386{a} 
  libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxinerama1:i386{a} 
  libxpm4:i386{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} odbcinst{a} 
  odbcinst1debian2{a} p11-kit-modules:i386{a} p7zip{a} ttf-wqy-microhei{a} 
  unixodbc{a} wine-gecko2.21{a} wine-gecko2.21:i386{a} wine-mono0.0.8{a} 
  wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64{a} wine1.6-i386:i386{a} winetricks{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 53 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 152 MB of archives. After unpacking 487 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd3 : Breaks: libgd3:i386 (!= 2.1.1-4.1+deb.sury.org~wily+1) but 2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.3 is to be installed.
 libgd3:i386 : Breaks: libgd3 (!= 2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.3) but 2.1.1-4.1+deb.sury.org~wily+1 is installed.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libgd3:i386 [Not Installed]                        
2)     libgphoto2-6:i386 [Not Installed]                  
3)     libsane:i386 [Not Installed]                       
4)     wine1.6 [Not Installed]                            
5)     wine1.6-amd64 [Not Installed]                      
6)     wine1.6-i386:i386 [Not Installed]                  

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
7)     winetricks recommends wine                         
8)     wine1.6-i386:i386 recommends libsane:i386          


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

I tried update, upgrade, dist-upgrade, install -f, adding x32 architecture, etc...

Install -f:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any more ideas into how to solve this?

Comment: See this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/697648/how-to-fix-installation-wine-on-ubuntu-14-04-3lts-64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to downgrade libgd3.

```
sudo apt-get install libgd3=2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.3
```

Problem solved.